# To Convert Calendar java code to C# (Xamarin (android))

Tags: android, xamarin, calendar

I saw these:

```
    Calendar cin = Calendar.getInstance();
    cin.setTime(dateInput);

    iYear  = cin.get(Calendar.YEAR); 
    iMonth = cin.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1; 
    iDay   = cin.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH); 


        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.set(Calendar.YEAR, iYear);
        c.set(Calendar.MONTH, iMonth-1);
        c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, iDay);
        c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, dfHourRise);
        c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, dfMinRise);
```

How can I convert these to C#? I want to use these in xamarin (android).

It is correct?

```
            Calendar cin = Calendar.Instance;
            ?
            iYear = cin.Get(CalendarField.Year);
            iMonth = cin.Get(CalendarField.Month) + 1;
            iDay = cin.Get(CalendarField.DayOfMonth);
```

EDITED:
I used this code and saw correct outputs:

```
    Calendar c = Calendar.Instance;
    c.TimeInMillis = Java.Lang.JavaSystem.CurrentTimeMillis();
    var iYear = c.Get(CalendarField.Year);
    var iMonth = c.Get(CalendarField.Month) + 1;
    var iDay = c.Get(CalendarField.DayOfMonth);
    var iHour = c.Get(CalendarField.Hour);
    var iMinute = c.Get(CalendarField.Minute);
    var iSecond = c.Get(CalendarField.Second);
```

Comment: You would just use the `Calendar` type in Xamarin. You can find documentation on this class here: https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Java.Util.Calendar/ Thus you would use the respective `Set()` overloaded methods to define your `Calendar` object and grab the values via public properties.

Comment: You are right to get the current time by `Calendar`.

Comment: I edited my question. I saw correct outputs. All things are correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use C#'s DateTime for the same purpose. It is much better and advanced than java.util.calendar

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;

var year = dt.Year;
var month = dt.Month;
var day = dt.Day;
var hour = dt.Hour;
var min = dt.Minute;
var second = dt.Second;
```

make the most of C#'s features when you're developing in Xamarin